# How to plot the data from the columns onto a world map in altair python

Tags: javascript, python, data-visualization, altair, vega-lite

For a visualization project, I have the following (sample) dataset:

```
country|continent|rank|house|total|year
 france|Eu       |a   |top  |23   |2010
 france|Eu       |b   |top  |21   |2010
 france|Eu       |b   |mid  |19   |2012
 italy |Eu       |b   |top  |25   |2010
 italy |Eu       |a   |top  |26   |2012
 china |asia     |b   |mid  |35   |2010
 korea |asia     |a   |mid  |29   |2010
 china |asia     |a   |top  |40   |2012
 korea |asia     |b   |top  |33   |2012
 kenya |africa   |b   |mid  |20   |2010
 kenya |africa   |c   |mid  |18   |2012
```

I want to plot the information on a world map using altair to obtain something like this:

[image]

(to note: I need only one world map - not two like the picture)

What I intend is - have the total column as the red dots (size according to number) which on hover over shows the value of the (sum) total. And on the side - preferably right side or the top, I want to create a selector(dropdown) for the years, rank and house with an interactivity option such that -

ex. In france - if I select house - top, the total showing should be 44 while for selecting house-mid, the total should be 19.
And as last step - I want to have the continent selector-dropdown such that if a continent is selected that part zooms in.

I have started using altair recently and I know how to build individual components like dropdown or concatenating two charts etc. As for world map -

```js
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

# Data generators for the background
sphere = alt.sphere()
graticule = alt.graticule()

# Source of land data
source = alt.topo_feature(data.world_110m.url, 'countries')

# Layering and configuring the components
alt.layer(
    alt.Chart(sphere).mark_geoshape(fill='lightblue'),
    alt.Chart(graticule).mark_geoshape(stroke='white', strokeWidth=0.5),
    alt.Chart(source).mark_geoshape(fill='ForestGreen', stroke='black')
).project(
    'naturalEarth1'
).properties(width=600, height=400).configure_view(stroke=None)
```

Its the code sample in altair documentation, but I really donot know how to attain my objectives. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The University of Washington has a [good intro notebook for Altair geo plotting](https://github.com/uwdata/visualization-curriculum/blob/master/altair_cartographic.ipynb). For your situation, you could [plot the map and the scatter in two different charts and combine them as in this example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/airports_count.html).

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

airports = data.airports.url
states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, feature='states')

# US states background
background = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(
    fill='lightgray',
    stroke='white'
).properties(
    width=500,
    height=300
).project('albersUsa')

# airport positions on background
points = alt.Chart(airports).transform_aggregate(
    latitude='mean(latitude)',
    longitude='mean(longitude)',
    count='count()',
    groupby=['state']
).mark_circle().encode(
    longitude='longitude:Q',
    latitude='latitude:Q',
    size=alt.Size('count:Q', title='Number of Airports'),
    color=alt.value('steelblue'),
    tooltip=['state:N','count:Q']
).properties(
    title='Number of airports in US'
)

background + points
```

[image]